# A question about pre-additive category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $C$ be a pre-additive category with a zero object $O$. Suppose that every morphism
in $C$ has a kernel and a cokernel and that every monomorphism in $C$ is a kernel of
some morphism. Prove that every morphism $f$ in $C$ can be written as $hg$ for some
epimorphism $g$ and monomorphism $h$.

How to prove it? I have no way to solve. Thanks.

Comment: The formal dual of the proof given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/548307/5191) works.

Comment: @Zhen: Isn't this an answer?